# What's wrong with my code? why gets function is not working?

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, gets

I have declared 3 variables. here ch for store one character and s for store a single word and sen for a sentence or multiple words!
But, when i run the code it is not giving the opportunity to give an input for sen variable.

I have tried to figure out the problem. but I failed!
What's wrong with my code. can anyone help me please...

Here is my code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch, s[20], sen[100];
    scanf("%c%s",&ch,&s);
    gets(sen);
    printf("%c\n%s\n%s", ch, s, sen);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, never ***ever*** use `gets`! [It's so dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) it has even been removed from the C language. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Beyond that, the `Enter` key you have pressed for the first`scanf` input will be written to the input buffer as a newline `'\n'`. This will be the first character read by `fgets` (or `gets` in your code). The function will treat it as the end of the line, and not read anything else.

Comment: Md Nasir Ahmed, what was your exact input?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your valuable information! I just overcome it by using \n in the scanf line.
   ` scanf("%c%s\n",&ch,&s);`

Comment: Md Nasir Ahmed,  reading with `%s` will not save input with spaces in it like a typical _sentence_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I just tried to input 3 different types of character or string. like first one for a single character, 2nd one for a single word and third one for a single line.

Comment: Md Nasir Ahmed, Rather than only [descibe the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987691/whats-wrong-with-my-code-why-gets-function-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment121925572_68987691), what was your exact input?

Comment: Sorry, I think i couldn't explain my thoughts. @chux-ReinstateMonica I was trying to input these things..
`c
cool
its really cool`

but i was able to give only 2 input. not 3. that was my problem.

Comment: Trailing white-space isn't the proper solution either. It happens to work for your specific case, but it's a bad habit which will lead to problem in other situations. One possible naive solution is to use a loop reading character by character until the newline (or end of file). A much better solution is to not use `scanf` at all, but use `fgets` to read whole lines, and then possibly use `sscanf` to parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `gets` function for buffer overflow. Use `fgets()` instead.

`fgets()` takes 3 arguments.
one is str >>> pointer to an initialized string in which characters are copied. it also returns str.

another is int n >>> number of characters to copy.

and finally, file stream or stdin >>> reading from standard input.

Use

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    char* s[20], sen[100];
    scanf("%c%*c\n", &ch);
    scanf_s("%19s", s, 20);
    fgets(sen, 100, stdin);
    printf("%c\n%s\n%s", ch, s, sen);
    return 0;
}
```

You are missing  `&sen` which is supposed to take the input.

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.: "warning: format '%s' expects argument of type '`char *`', but argument 3 has type '`char (*)[20]`' [-Wformat=]   `scanf("%c%s",&ch,&s,&sen);`", "warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]  `scanf("%c%s",&ch,&s,&sen);`"

Comment: okay edited the answer. Hope it works fine now.

Comment: Still generates warnings.  Also `scanf("%s", &s);`, without a width in the specifier nor checking the result  is worse than `gets()`.  Same for `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &sen);`.  Strange to read into `sen` twice.

Comment: edited the answer. Is it still generating warnings?

Comment: Of course it is.  Enable all compiler warnings to rapidly check for yourself.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, as I am a beginner. I don't have enough knowledge about these kind of warnings and don't know how to debug and solve these problems. :(

Comment: yeah, sorry I haven't checked I used fgets() for sen... edited and used "\n" to be more specific

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you for advising to use specifier. Edited the answer using specifier for s with having null terminator space. Hope this won't generate the warning now.

Comment: @FatinIshrakRafi Research your compilers warning settings.  It is well work the time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sure and thanks. I learned C a long ago when I started programming, basically, I now work on Python. But I'll revise these kinds of stuff managing some time.